# jQuery draggable, event when dropped outside of parent div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a list of photos, and I have draggable added to them, however when the photo is dragged outside of the parent div, I want to change it's class so it indicates that if you drop it, it will be removed, and then when the user drops it, I want it to fire a function. (only if it is outside of the parent div)

```
<ul class="photos">
<li><img src=""/></li>
<li><img src=""/></li>
</ul>
```

so when an li is dragged outside of .photos, it fires to add class, and then if it's dropped outside of it, then it fires and event to remove it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming the parent `div` you mention is a droppable, you can bind an event handler to the [`dropout`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-out) event:

```
$("#parentDiv").on("dropout", function(event, ui) {
    //ui.draggable refers to the draggable
});
```

The event will fire any time an accepted draggable is dragged outside the tolerance area of the droppable.

**Update** (see comments)

You can supply a callback function to the `revert` option. The function can take one argument which either contains the droppable on which the draggable was dropped, or `false` (if it was dropped somewhere invalid):

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    revert: function(valid) {
        if(!valid) {
            //Dropped outside of valid droppable
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/vjGY4/).

Comment: This works for adding the class to it, however what about detecting when it's actually dropped?

Comment: This fires when you drag it outside of the droppable. I thought that's what you wanted, so you could add a class to the draggable when it's dragged outside of the droppable?

Comment: Yes i do, but how would I detect when it's actually dropped outside?