# Cant select my cloned draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently doing a Web App that can drag and drop image with resize.
But when I append the cloned element on the `#dropzone`, I can't select it anymore.

So here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".draggable").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move'
    });
    $("#dropzone").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var canvas = $(this);
            if (!ui.draggable.hasClass('object')) {
                var canvasElement = ui.helper.clone();
                canvasElement.addClass('object');
                canvasElement.removeClass('draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging')
                canvas.append(canvasElement);
                canvasElement.draggable({
                    containment: '#garden',
                    stack:       canvasElement
                }).find("img").css({
                    'width':   50,
                    'height':  50
                }).resizable({
                    minWidth:  50, 
                    minHeight: 50,
                    containment:'#garden'
                });
                canvasElement.css({
                    left:     (ui.position.left),
                    top:      (ui.position.top),
                    position: 'absolute',
                    zIndex:   3                
                });
            } 
        } 
    });

    $(".object").click(function(event, ui) {
        alert("WOOOOO!");
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

my click function on `.object` isn't working. I dont know why. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to keep dragging the cloned element, you should add the following code to your #dropzone drop function:

```
canvasElement.draggable({
    cursor: 'move'
});
```

This is because when $(".draggable").draggable was executed your new canvasElement didn't exist yet and that's also why your click event doesn't work, so also add the following to your #dropzone drop function:

```
canvasElement.click(function(event, ui) {
    alert("WOOOOO!");
});
```

If you want to do something when you drop out of the dropzone check out this thread: [jQuery draggable, event when dropped outside of parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317293/jquery-draggable-event-when-dropped-outside-of-parent-div)

(check http://codepen.io/ptcardoso/pen/xErxJm)

Comment: What i want to happen is to control the cloned element in the #dropzone like hide,change style, re-size,display alert. But my code on the click function isn't working. I've tried to add your suggestion but nothing happens.

Comment: Did you check my codepen for clarification? The click and drag events work on the cloned element

Comment: Oh okay. It makes sense now. Thank you sir Pedro.