# how to stop dragging outside a container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this plugin for the [mind map](http://kenneth.kufluk.com/google/js-mindmap/) the full code that deals with the dragging is [in this link.](http://kenneth.kufluk.com/google/js-mindmap/js-mindmap.js)

This is the html I am using in my case, constraining the mindmap in a custom dive while the example goes to full body.

**HTML**

```
<div id="myMap"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#myMap {
    min-height: 300px;
    width:      500px;
}
```

This is what I am trying with console error:

```
    this.el.draggable({
        drag:function() {
            obj.root.animateToStatic();
        }
        appendTo:    "body",
        helper:      "clone",
        revert:      "invalid",
        cursor:      "move",
        containment: "#myMap",
        zIndex:      10000,
        scroll:      false,
        start:       function (event, ui) {
            this.el.hide();
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            this.el.show();
        }
    });
```

**Error:**

> ```
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
> mind_js.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mindmap is not a function
> ```

the second error refers to another file which is fine, the error appears as the code below breaks the js, causing other issues in other js.

Also looked at [other SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317293/jquery-draggable-event-when-dropped-outside-of-parent-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing a comma...

```
  this.el.draggable({
    drag:function() {
        obj.root.animateToStatic();
    },
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    cursor: "move",
    containment: "#myMap",
    zIndex: 10000,
    scroll:false,
    start: function (event, ui) {
        this.el.hide();
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        this.el.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: oh wow, i cannot believe this is what it was! Apologise. thanks a lot

Comment: Actually this stops the dragging completely and it appends to body all the dragging elements

Comment: removing the appendTo resolves it yet what i was trying to do is to constrain the dragging within the div